# Problems installing/working with DCKit on XCode/Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have successfully downloaded and installed Cocoapods on my Macbook via terminal. I then 'cd' to my directory that holds my .xcodeproj and in the terminal create a new pod 'pod init'. I edit the 'Podfile' in Xcode by uncommenting platform :ios, '9.0'
and add 'pod 'DCKit', '~> 1.0''
so it looks like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'myApp' do
       use_frameworks!
       pod 'DCKit', '~> 1.0'

    target 'myAppTests' do
       inherit! :search_paths

    end

    target 'myAppUITests' do
      inherit! :search_paths

    end

  end
```

I save the file, & exit Xcode. I then 'pod install' in my terminal, get all the success messages:

"Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed."

Then I reopen XCode and I cannot see or find the DCKit. Please help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After 'pod install' cocoapods makes a new file with the suffix .xcworkspace in your same .xcodeproj directory. Instead of opening the .xcodeproj file, open the .xcworkspace file and the module is ready to use.